# Retrieving user id by ignoring undefined user

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

I am logged in as a particular user and I am trying to retrieve the user id of the current user and then with it I want to make a call to a REST API to retrieve how many points this user has, the code is:

```js
getPoints(): Observable<number> {
  return this.userAccount.get().pipe(
    switchMap(userOrUndefined => {
      console.log("User retrieved:" + userOrUndefined?.customerId)
      return this.pointsRetrievalService.getPoints(userOrUndefined);
    }),
    catchError(error => of(error)
  ))
}
```

where "userAccount" type is `protected userAccount: UserAccountFacade`
here is the class

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../model/user.model';
import * as i0 from "@angular/core";

export declare abstract class UserAccountFacade {
  abstract get(): Observable<User | undefined>;
  static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<UserAccountFacade, never>;
  static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<UserAccountFacade>;
}
```

The issue I face is that "userAccount.get().subscribe(..)" returns firstly "undefined" an calls the service to retrieve the points and then it returns the real user and calls the service to retrieve points

```
Retrieving user:undefined
pointsRetrievalService called
Retreiving user:eb6cb3de-4107-4ef9-9d95-e0fb83e5c200
pointsRetrievalService called
```

How can I make it ignore the "undefined" user and call the get points service only with the first non "undefined" returned from this.userAccount.get()?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` operator, to only receive defined value.
But be careful your stream will wait (and be blocked) if no correct `User` is emitted.

```js
getPoints(): Observable<number> {

  return this.userAccount.get().pipe(
    filter(userOrUndefined => !!userOrUndefined),
    switchMap(user => {
      console.log("User retrieved:" + user.customerId)
      return this.pointsRetrievalService.getPoints(user);
    }), 
    catchError(error => of(error))
  )
}
```

It's possible to improve `!!userOrUndefined` syntax with :

```js
typeof userOrUndefined !== 'undefined' && userOrUndefined !== null
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned @Sergey, we can even simplify filtering operator as below:

`filter(userOrUndefined => !!userOrUndefined)` could be replaced by `filter(Boolean)`.

[More explanation about Boolean object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

Comment: Or simply `filter(Boolean)`

Comment: The code doesn't seem to compile since it is sayinng "user" might be "undefined"

Comment: @Sergey can you please show how can this be done with filter(Boolean)?

Comment: Just replace the filter in the code with my suggestion. If it complains about possible undefined try updating rxjs version. They improved type narrowing in v7

Comment: @Sergey aha I am with 6.6.0 :(

Comment: @Sergey any suggestions how this can be done with version less than v7?

Comment: With RxJS@6, try this :  `filter((userOrUndefined): userOrUndefined is User => !!userOrUndefined)`